# Print the difference between 2 timetamps in a file unix

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

```
 cat A 
        ROW1COL1 ROW1COL2 2013-08-26 22:07:26  2013-08-26 22:07:26
        ROW2COL1 ROW2COL2 2013-08-26 22:08:16  2013-08-26 22:08:20
        (2 rows)
```

The  objective is to capture the rows which have the difference  of greater than  3 seconds between the timestamps.

```
        output here is 
        ROW2COL1 ROW2COL2 2013-08-26 22:08:16  2013-08-26 22:08:20

        I tried the below.

        bash-3.2$ echo $d1
        08/28/2013 16:56:36
        bash-3.2$ echo $d2
        08/28/2013 16:56:44
        bash-3.2$ date1=$(date -d "$d1" +%s)
        bash-3.2$ date2=$(date -d "$d2" +%s)
        bash-3.2$ diff=$(expr $date2 - $date1)
        bash-3.2$ echo $diff
        8
          i am getting syntax error with the "%s" while using awk command.
        Here are 2 variations i tried.but 

        awk '{t1=$3" "$4;t2=$5" "$6;time2=$(date -d "$t2" +%s);time1=$(date -d "$t1" +%s); if ($(expr $time2 - $time1) > 3) print $0 }' A
```

Answer (score 1):

Awk has a built-in mktime() method that does the equivalent of `date -d ... +%s` except the format of the date input must be "YYYY MM DD hh mm ss".

```
awk '
    {
            t1=$3" "$4;
            t2=$5" "$6;

            gsub(/[-:]/, " ", t1);
            gsub(/[-:]/, " ", t2);

            time1 = mktime(t1);
            time2 = mktime(t2);

            if ( ( time2 - time1 ) > 3 )
                    print $0
    }' A
```

By the way, the awk script as you have it is mixing shell syntax inside an awk script.  That's why the errors.

**For Awk without mktime**

```
awk '
    {
            t1=$3" "$4;
            t2=$5" "$6;

            cmd1 = "date -d \"" t1 "\" +%s";
            cmd2 = "date -d \"" t2 "\" +%s";

            cmd1 | getline time1;
            cmd2 | getline time2;

            if ( ( time2 - time1 ) > 3 )
                    print $0
    }' A
```

Comment: I think you mean GNU awk has `mktime`. [XCU awk](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcu/awk.html) doesn't, nor does awk on OS X or FreeBSD.

Comment: Ah, is that so.  That stinks ;-).  I'll add the alternative to the answer.

Comment: Updated the answer to include a version that doesn't use mktime.

Comment: @ash Thanks a  ton!!  the  first one worked!  but the second one prints timestamps for  time2 < time1  .

Comment: Glad to hear it worked.  Odd that the second one gets it backwards.  I don't see the mistake.